# For Loop to insert multiple rows in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node-red

I have the following incoming payload:

```
msg.payload : array [16]
[ "C-2B", "C-3A", "C-3B", "C-3C", "C-3E", "C-3F", "C-4A", "C-4B", "C-4D", "C-4E", "C-4F", "C-5A", "C-5B", "C-5C", "C-5D", "C-5E" ]
```

The above payload is being inputted into the following function node (which will then be forwarded to the appropriate opt_alarms table:

```
for ( i = 0; i < msg.payload.length; i++){
    insert = "INSERT INTO opt_alarms VALUES (now(),'RECEIVING', '"+ String(msg.payload[i]) +"')";
    return {topic:insert, payload:insert}
}
```

I'm trying to parse the incoming payload and have it list each value, from the incoming array, on a separate row within that opt_alarms TABLE. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to return from the function since that will bail out of the whole function the first time round the loop, you want `node.send(msg}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use return inside a loop, I would recommend using `map` instead of a for loop.  So instead of a for loop:

```
var statements = msg.payload.map(function(x){
    return "INSERT INTO opt_alarms VALUES (now(),'RECEIVING', '" + string(x) + "'";
});
```

This is not quite equivalent but since you are creating a two element object with the same sql in both, it at least transforms the array of values into an array of SQL statements.

This is not SQL injection safe so you want to look carefully to see if parameterized queries are supported and if not make sure you sanitize your input to MySQL specifications.

Comment: I think you miss the closing bracket on VALUES statement, otherwise it is a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Travers solution is working great if you want to have an INSERT statement for each value in `msg.payload`. With some modifications like this:

```
var insertIntoSql = "INSERT INTO opt_alarms VALUES " + msg.payload.map(function(x){
    return  "(now(),'RECEIVING', '" + String(x) + "')";
}).join(',');
```

You can have a single INSERT statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO opt_alarms VALUES
(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-2B'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-3A'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-3B'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-3C'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-3E'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-3F'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-4A'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-4B'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-4D'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-4E'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-4F'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-5A'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-5B'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-5C'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-5D'),(now(),'RECEIVING', 'C-5E')
```